# Saving the state of multiple checkboxes for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I created a button to create multiple checkbox on no. of clicks for wp7. Below the codes I used for it.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
   <TextBox x:Name="txtNewTask" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="328"/>
   <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="328,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Click="btnAdd_Click"/>
   <ListBox x:Name="lbToDoList" Margin="0,72,0,0">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <CheckBox Click="CheckBox_Click" Background="{x:Null}">
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Name="tbkTextName" VerticalAlignment="Center"     Margin="5,0,5,0" />
           </StackPanel>
         </CheckBox>
       </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Now when I exit and re-open my app, I noticed the checkbox’s are unchecked (default state) and its state is not saved. Can you please help me to save the multiple checkbox's value or state?

Can anybody help me to **save the multiple checkbox's state**. Thanks in advance for your help!

[image: Image of the created checkboxes]

Answer (score 0):

Use [IsolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.applicationsettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Here are two helper methods for accessing application settings

```
    /// Get the current value of the setting, or if it is not found, set the 
    /// setting to the default setting.
    protected valueType GetValueOrDefault<valueType>(string Key, valueType defaultValue)
    {
        valueType value;
        object storedValue = null;

        try
        {
            if (_isolatedStore.TryGetValue(Key, out storedValue))
            {
                value = (valueType)(_isolatedStore[Key] ?? defaultValue);
            }
            else
            {
                //the key was not found
                value = defaultValue;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            value = defaultValue;
            Logger.Error(ex, "Exception while getting IsolatedStorageSettings: ");
        }


        return value;
    }

    protected bool AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, Object value)
    {
        bool valueChanged = false;
        object storedValue = null;

        try
        {
            if (_isolatedStore.TryGetValue(Key, out storedValue))
            {
                if (storedValue != value)
                {
                    _isolatedStore[Key] = value;
                    valueChanged = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //the key was not found
                _isolatedStore.Add(Key, value);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex, "Exception while adding IsolatedStorageSettings.");
        }

        return valueChanged;
    }
```

And you can then create a property on some settings class or view model that is backed by IsolatedStorage like this.

```
    string CheckBoxValueKeyName = "checkbox_value";
    bool CheckBoxValueDefault = false;

    public bool CheckBoxValue
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValueOrDefault<bool>(CheckBoxValueKeyName, CheckBoxValueDefault );
        }
        set
        {
            AddOrUpdateValue(CheckBoxValueKeyName, value);
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to apply the changes of checking the box immediately to isolated storage, the [WP7 Tombstone Helper](http://tombstonehelper.codeplex.com/) is a quick way to persist the state of your controls after the app tombstones.  So, yes, for persistent storage after the application is closed use Isolated Storage.

Comment: I tried wp7 tombstone helper but didn't work. There is nothing complex scenarios in my app. Just need to to save the values.

Comment: The tombstone helper helps, well, when your app is tombstoned; you are looking for persistent storage.  Isolated storage is the way to go, and a Boolean will fit nicely in the part of IsolatedStorage reserved for application settings as suggested by @Rico-E.  It is a dictionary for simple data types.  However, his example doesn't check for null values.  Use TryGetValue  and return a default value in null cases.  This page http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-store-data-in-isolatedstoragesettings from the article linked to by jimpanzer gives examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save data to a time when your application is not running. For that staff I use `IsolatedStorage`. You can save anything, what you need. I found great [tutorial](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files), how it implement. hope it's help.

Answer (score 0):

I Think the best way is, to save the value of the checkbox instantly when it changes.
To do so you can do the following:

Assume that the check box in the myPage.xaml looks like:

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Title}" Name="myAutoSavingCheckBox" Click="myAutoSavingCheckBox_Click"/>
```

In the myPage.xaml.cs you have to define the following method:

```
private void myAutoSavingCheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.ViewModel.MyProperty = myAutoSavingCheckBox.IsChecked;
    }
```

The `App.ViewModel` is declared in the App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
...
    public static MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            // Erstellung des Ansichtsmodells verzögern bis erforderlich
            if (viewModel == null)
                viewModel = new MainViewModel();

            return viewModel;
        }
    }
...
}
```

Now you define your Property and the saving Function in the MainViewModel.cs as follows:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private bool? myProperty;
    public bool? MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return myProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != myProperty)
            {
                myProperty = value;
                SaveSetting("MyProperty", myProperty);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SaveSettings(string whatShallBeSavedKey, object whatShallBeSavedValue)
    {
        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("whatShallBeSavedKey"))
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["whatShallBeSavedKey"] = whatShallBeSavedValue;
        else
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("whatShallBeSavedKey", whatShallBeSavedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this code, it saves only one checkbox(myAutoSavingCheckBox). But i want to save the value of multiple checkbox that's already created. See my edited post.